# SpringBoot Selenium Automation

Tags: selenium, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

I have created Spring Boot web app and its working fine. Now I am writing selenium automation for my web app. I have written some test case. But when I am executing the test cases by using mvn test its giving following exception.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials

Can someone tell me why this is error?

Comment: You may need to moq authentication ?

Comment: Formatted error as quote

Answer (score 0):

You might missing the jar

make sure you have `httpclient 4.5.2` or higher in your class path.

#### refresh eclipse

- Close Eclipse.
- clean .m2/repository folder
- Open Eclipse and Alt+F5 on project;
- check option Force Update of Snapshots

Comment: It works but now facing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/RegistryBuilder

Comment: Added below dependency one and now working fine. Thanks    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
   <version>4.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
  </dependency>

Comment: @DeadProgrammer , you can accept and up vote the answer so that others will get help from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.+</version>
</dependency>
```

and check